# How to show how scales of adjacent subplots relate to each other?

Tags: data-visualization

I have a bar plot and my data is clearly on two different scales:

[image]

Unfortunately log transforming is not an option. I'm trying to figure out if there's a nice way to split it over two subplots, while capturing how the scales relate to each other. Something almost like this:

[image]

... I'm thinking though that there could be a way to link the axes, similar to how maps show a blown up region like this:

[image]

Is there a name for this kind of figure? I've done some searching, but don't think I've found the right search terms.

Comment: Have you considered using a logarithmic scale on the y-axis?

Comment: Yes, that's not an option in this case (I'll update the question)

Comment: Oops I have a downvote.. is this off-topic on this site?

Comment: Wasn't me.  It doesn't seem off-topic.

Comment: This one came to mind... https://www.xkcd.com/2023/

Comment: @CrisLuengo Really? I thought linking the axes "like the map" would makes the subplots _less_ misleading...

Comment: I didn’t mean to imply you were trying to mislead. I just imagined linking the vertical axes of the two plots in your second figure, and that lead me to think of the XKCD cartoon. It was literally a stream of consciousness. :)